# Open clicked image inside image control (asp.net/c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, hyperlink

Inside my application I'm generating some images inside hyperlink controls that opens up the image in full size. I have a image control at the top of the page where I want the clicked image to be displayed, but with the code I have that doesn't work.

What happens is that the clicked image is opened on a new page, so what I wonder is how to make the image appear in the image control?

```
<asp:Image ID="fullSizeImage" runat="server" />

<asp:HyperLink ID="link" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Name", "...directory...") %>' >
    <asp:Image ID="Image" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Name", "...directory...") %>' CssClass="thumb" />
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<script runat="server">
    protected void thumbImage_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        fullSizeImage.ImageUrl = "full size image path goes here";
    }
</script>

<asp:Image ID="fullSizeImage" runat="server" />
<asp:ImageButton ID="thumbImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="image path goes here" onclick="thumbImage_Click" />
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Regarding the click event, how can I "extract" the ImageUrl from the clicked image and pass it to the event?

Comment: If you want to use the same image as the one used in your thumbnail, then you can do the following: fullSizeImage.ImageUrl = thumbImage.ImageUrl; on the thumbImage_Click handler. However, for performance reasons, you should have a real thumbnail image and the full size image instead of shrinking the full image and using it for the thumbnail.

Comment: It didn't appear in my question, but the imageUrl for the thumbnail goes to a directory for thumbnails (ie. "real" thumbnails). The only difference in the directories between the full size images and the thumbnails is "/thumbnails/". Do I need to split up the address to be able to remove "/thumbnails/", or do you know if there's an easier way? Thanks again.

Comment: The url is a string, you can just use .Replace("thumbnails", "real");

Comment: Ok, great. One last thing. By some strange reason I can't access the ID of the ImageButton inside the event "doesn't exist in the context...". I have the ImageButton inside an ItemTemplate, could that be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

put an `img` tag in an `anchor` tag and give

`src='<%#Eval("put image address from table column")%>'`

and put that same value in the link

`href='<%#Eval("put image address from table column")%>'`